# How to make a HTTP POSTrequest to an API using headers

Tags: php, laravel, api, http-post, postman

I need to integrate an API into my app.
The docs say:

**HTTP POST
    The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.**

```
POST /partnerhubwebservice.asmx/Authorise HTTP/1.1
Host: stage.example.co.uk
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

username=string&password=string
```

and response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AuthorisationResult xmlns="http://webservice.example.co.uk/">
  <Token>string</Token>
</AuthorisationResult>
```

Reading the docs I create this function in Laravel Controller:

```
public function testRld() {

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
try {
    $res = $client->post('http://stage.example.co.uk/partnerhubwebservice.asmx/Authorise', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ],
    'x-www-form-urlencoded' => [
        'Username' => 'MMM_bookings',
        'Password' => 'passwordaaaa',
]
            ]);

return $res;

}

catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $result =  json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    return response()->json(['data' => $result]);

    }

}
```

but I got a message:

> ServerException in RequestException.php line 111: Server error: `POST
>   http://stage.example.co.uk/partnerhubwebservice.asmx/Authorise`
>   resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: Missing parameter:
>   username.

When I try this at POSTMAN app everything is fine and there I get response ike:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AuthorisationResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://webservice.example.co.uk/">
    <RequestSuccessful>true</RequestSuccessful>
    <ErrorMessage />
    <Token>27d67d31-999-44e0-9851-d6f427fd2181</Token>
</AuthorisationResult>
```

Please help me to solve this problem? What is wrong with my code? WHy I got the error , and POSTMAN request works fine ...

Comment: `username` != `Username`. Start by seeing if it's being case sensitive.

Comment: Maybe a case issue?  You wrote Username, not username

Comment: Your username and password start with a capital letter

Comment: I try but that was not a problem ... again I got the same error message

Comment: Have a go at doing it the way [the guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#post-form-requests) says.

Comment: @JonStirling what is that way ?

Comment: The way it says in the link I posted......

Comment: but why POSTMAN works fine and my code wont?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending username and password inside of a body as `body` or `json`, instead of as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, like so:

```
$res = $client->post('http://stage.example.co.uk/partnerhubwebservice.asmx/Authorise', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ],
    'json' => [
        'username' => 'MMM_bookings',
        'password' => 'passwordaaaa',
    ]
]);
```

or

```
$res = $client->post('http://stage.example.co.uk/partnerhubwebservice.asmx/Authorise', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ],
    'body' => [
        'username' => 'MMM_bookings',
        'password' => 'passwordaaaa',
    ]
]);
```

Comment: They're not in the `headers` section.

Comment: What version of guzzle/http are you using?

Comment: "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"

Comment: Try changing `json` or `body` to `form_params`

Comment: When I change to form_params I got: FatalErrorException in Router.php line 1227:
Class 'Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\HttpFoundationFactory' not found

Comment: And whats your Laravel version?

Comment: Try installing these 2 dependencies and try the call again `composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge` and `composer require zendframework/zend-diactoros`

Comment: Pa kada praviš ovakve requeste potrebno ti je da imaš instaliran ovaj symfony dependency, evo ti i link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#psr7-requests

Comment: Vazi, hvala ti, probacu... Da li je moguce napraviti requeste bez ovih biblioteka? Vec sam probao neke API-e i nisu zahtevali ove biblioteke...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164789/discussion-between-nikola-gavric-and-aleks-per).

Answer (score 0):

Use [form_params](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params):

```
$client->request('POST', 'http://stage.example.co.uk/partnerhubwebservice.asmx/Authorise', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ],
    'form_params' => [
        'username' => 'MMM_bookings',
        'password' => 'password'
    ]
]);
```

> The PSR-7 standard specifies interfaces for HTTP messages, including requests and responses. If you would like to obtain an instance of a PSR-7 request instead of a Laravel request, you will first need to install a few libraries. Laravel uses the Symfony HTTP Message Bridge component to convert typical Laravel requests and responses into PSR-7 compatible implementations:

Install the necessary dependencies as well:

```
composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge
composer require zendframework/zend-diactoros
```

Comment: I got error message: FatalErrorException in Router.php line 1227:
Class 'Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\HttpFoundationFactory' not found ... ALSO when I try form_params at POSTMAN wont work ...

Comment: Sounds like you are missing dependencies, check my answer update.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I will try. IS POSSIBLE TO MAKE REQUESTS WITOUT INSTALLING THIS LIBRARIES ?

Comment: No psr7 compliant messages are required with guzzle.