# Call Rest Api Using Zend\Http\Client Or Guzzle

Tags: rest, zend-framework, zend-framework2, magento2, guzzle

I am calling magento2 API in laravel. Using curl, I am getting correct response but I want to call API using GuzzleHttp\Client or Zend\Http\Client.
How can I call my api using this, below is my curl code snippet:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    $data=array('username'=>$vendordata['merchant_name'],'password'=>$vendordata['password'],'customer'=>['email'=>$vendordata['email'],"firstname"=> $vendordata['firstname'], "lastname"=> $vendordata['lastname']],"addresses"=> ["region"=> $vendordata['address'], "region_id"=> 0],"default_shipping"=> true,"default_billing"=>true,"telephone"=>$vendordata['contact_number']);
    $postdata=json_encode($data);

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://10.10.10.7/magento2/rest/V1/customers",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"sganfgvr2naxwmh21jgi5ffijuci0207\",oauth_token=\"d16pdq1avr1rs7h9745rc0x6py65a2vt\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1518006201\",oauth_nonce=\"4ghORA\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"Ztq5ErznqvCl18GomWv0F55t5OA%3D\"",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/json",
            "postman-token: 5ec55151-3365-7ffc-a6a4-ce5fe5bc451f"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, open the terminal and run this command to install Guzzle

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Then add these lines to include guzzle in the specific controller.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

Now, create a method you want to run to call the API and put the below code

```
$client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
$result = $client->post('your-request-uri', [
    'form_params' => [
        'sample-form-data' => 'value'
    ]
]);
```

That's it!

Docs explain this pretty well : https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code when using guzzlehttp instead of curl

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://10.10.10.7/magento2/rest/V1/customers', array(
    headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="sganfgvr2naxwmh21jgi5ffijuci0207",oauth_token="d16pdq1avr1rs7h9745rc0x6py65a2vt",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1518006201",oauth_nonce="4ghORA",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="Ztq5ErznqvCl18GomWv0F55t5OA%3D',
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        'Postman-Token' => '5ec55151-3365-7ffc-a6a4-ce5fe5bc451f'
    ],
    'json' => $postdata
));
```

You also have to install following dependencies in your laravel project for [PSR-7 support](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#psr7-requests) and look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695178/how-to-make-a-http-postrequest-to-an-api-using-headers/48695367) as a reference:

```
composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge
composer require zendframework/zend-diactoros
```

Comment: I am getting this error: 400 Bad Request` response: {"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"customer"}}

Comment: Try using `form_params` instead of `json` as @TharinduLucky suggested below

Answer (score 0):

That caused by you didn't define the `Content-Type` as `application/json` on **HTTP Header**. Please try this

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://10.10.10.7/magento2/rest/V1/customers', array(
    headers' => [
        'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="sganfgvr2naxwmh21jgi5ffijuci0207",oauth_token="d16pdq1avr1rs7h9745rc0x6py65a2vt",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1518006201",oauth_nonce="4ghORA",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="Ztq5ErznqvCl18GomWv0F55t5OA%3D',
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        'Postman-Token' => '5ec55151-3365-7ffc-a6a4-ce5fe5bc451f'
    ],
    'json' => $postdata
));
```

And don't forget to load the dependencies using composer

```
composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge
composer require zendframework/zend-diactoros
```